# How to change overscroll glow color in ListPopupWindow?

Tags: android

I am using `ListPopupWindow` for EditText. I want to change the blue color of overscroll glow to red. How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried adding 
        `<item name="android:colorEdgeEffect">@color/color</item>`
to your theme?